# Java client application using wsdl file (local)

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a web service deployed on our own web server (not on any IIS or Tomcat)
. So, all I have is a WSDL file and a webserver.exe (that has the web
services implemented inside).

Using this WSDL file, I have already developed a client application in .net
(C#) which is running properly.

Now I have to create another client application in JAVA using the same WSDL.
But I dont know how to proceed (I am new to JAVA). To be specific I have some
questions to proceed for it.. Please see the code snippet I wrote in Java.

```java
trustAllHttpsCertificates();
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);

QName serviceName = new QName("Sphericall");
URL url = new URL("https","localhost",8085,"/SphericallService");

testthebest.Sphericall_Service service = new testthebest.Sphericall_Service
(url, serviceName);
//service.create(serviceName); 

testthebest.Sphericall port = service.getSphericall();
// TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
testthebest.StartSessionRequest value = new testthebest.StartSessionRequest();
```

In the above code segment, I have written code to bypass certificate check,
then for hostname verification and finally have tried to create the object of
service.

But while object creation I receive following exceptions. (WSDL not found).
Kindly note that in code I have assigned the new URL for service. And in
project I have attached the web reference (WSDL) which is kept in my
machine's D drive. So, Its was taking the URL as D:/xyz.wsdl but as its not
the correct path of URL so I changed it to "https://localhost:
8085/SphericallService". But its not running ..

```
com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of
InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://localhost:8085/SphericallService
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://localhost:8085/SphericallService?wsdl
```

As I said, My service is on our own developed webserver and it runs like a
executable (as an exe file). And the wsdl file is sepeartely provided. So, there is no path
exists like "https://localhost:8085/SphericallService?wsdl" for wsdl.

Kindly suggest if you have any idea on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java function wsimport to generate the client code to access your web service from the wsdl file. Example: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_jaxwsclientfromwsdl.html

Comment: I have already generated the client code i.e. the proxy classes.

Comment: I thought you weren't able to because of the path to your WSDL file (D:/)?

Comment: Java needs wsdl (generated proxy classes) at two levels, one at compile time (which is available in my case) and one at run time (which is missing in my case). 
If yes, then can't we bypass it using some method in java? Further why this .net (C#) doesn't require this wsdl at run time?